Размещение одного и того же go модуля на корпоративном gitlab и внешнем github репозиториях c возможностью полноценного go get
Возникла необходимость пушить коммиты в два репозитория корпоратиный gitlab и  внешний github. gitlab не имеет доступа в интернет. Нашел такое решение  git remote set-url --add --push origin  git@bitbucket.org.... Проект изначально создавался для локального gitlab соответсвено go.mod имеет соответствующую запись в директиве module. При попытке выполнить go get github.com/.... ругается module declares its path as: gitlab.... but was required as: github.com/...
Существует какой то workflow чтоб вести разработку с возможностью при необходимости использовать второй репозиторий как источник для скачивания модуля в сторонние проекты или возможно только использовать его как хранилище кода и go.mod надо править?

https://go.dev/wiki/Modules#when-should-i-use-the-replace-directive

Спасибо. Но там говорится про применение директивы replace. Это как я понимаю относится к управлению зависимостями текущего модуля. Но что если мне надо хранить кодовую базу данного модуля на разных репозиториях и иметь возможность применить к ней go get ?

Ну так другие модули могут использовать эту директиву и переопределять, откуда брать этот модуль.
